# How to split the argument passed inside python script

Tags: python-3.x, split

I have a python script new.py will rum the script in cron like below
New.py --indexname shri_red_n-1468790654980857394

Inside the script iam trying to tar the file based on the argument.

So while doing a tar i want only shri_red_n should ignore the number after it how would i do that.
Iam doing tarname="+indexname"+tar.gz"

Comment: this is my script

Comment: i want string to pick the value i pass as argument for table in below ex it has to pick 

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Give Splitter')
parser.add_argument('--table',dest='argument')
parser.add_argument('--schema',dest='argument')
args = parser.parse_args()
str=table
cf=str.split('-')[0]
print cf

Comment: this is how i run the script  python 2.py  --table abc-123 --schema efg-456 I want str to pick abc-123